# Why does the fundamental mode have the smallest loss in waveguide structures?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, waveguide

Why does the fundamental mode have the smallest loss in waveguide structures?And why the higher the order of the mode,the smaller the value of the angle between the light and the normal vector on the walls?

Comment: This is not true as stated, see the modes of the circular guide, especially TE11 v TE01. In general, though it is true that less spatial variation the field has the smaller its loss is, and that is because the wall dissipation is a kind of average of $E^2$.